# Get contents of a file from URL w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I want to request data from an API. It returns JSON formatted data like `{"numberOne":12345,"numberTwo":678}`

I tried this Javascript code but it gives me a syntax error because the answer is no JSONP but JSON

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://example.com/api',
  dataType: 'JSONP',
  jsonpCallback: 'callback',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function (data) {
      document.write(data);
  }
});
```

XMLHttpRequest is not working because the request is made to an other domain.

Maybe you know a **simple** way (I'm Javascript-Newbie) to get the data from the url. Is it possible to make the script ignoring the syntax of the response?

Comment: if the API provider does not support JSONP, and has not enabled cross-domain requests it means that they do not want their API accessed that way. Use a server side proxy to do it..

Comment: Obviously server doesn't allow you to do what you are looking for. Even you could proxify it server side, better thing would be to respect this third service and just don't do it!

Comment: If you can't use your own proxy you might also proxy through services like http://jsonp.jit.su/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change the data type to JSON

```
dataType: "json"
```

Read here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Thanks. Very easy. Don't know why I haven't come up with this idea on my own :D